# Flash plugin installation error

Tags: yum, adobe-flash

Somehow I found a repository for fedora core 3 flash plug-in. When I tried to install the flash plug-in I have encountered this error. I can't figure it out what does it mean, or how to solve this error.

```
[root@g22 ~]# yum install flash-plugin
Setting up Install Process
Setting up Repo:  opennms-unstable-fc7
repomd.xml                100% |=========================|  951 B    00:00
Setting up Repo:  opennms-testing-fc7
repomd.xml                100% |=========================|  951 B    00:00
Setting up Repo:  flash
repomd.xml                100% |=========================| 1.9 kB    00:00
Setting up Repo:  opennms-stable-fc7
repomd.xml                100% |=========================|  951 B    00:00
Setting up Repo:  opennms-snapshot-fc7
repomd.xml                100% |=========================|  951 B    00:00
Reading repository metadata in from local files
opennms-un: ################################################## 23/23
opennms-te: ################################################## 25/25
flash     : ################################################## 4/4
opennms-st: ################################################## 22/22
opennms-sn: ################################################## 27/27
Resolving Dependencies
--> Populating transaction set with selected packages. Please wait.
---> Downloading header for flash-plugin to pack into transaction set.
flash-plugin-9.0.48.0-a.i 100% |=========================| 5.9 kB    00:00
---> Package flash-plugin.i386 0:9.0.48.0-a set to be installed
--> Running transaction check

Dependencies Resolved
Transaction Listing:
  Install: flash-plugin.i386 0:9.0.48.0-a
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
flash-plugin-9.0.48.0-a.i 100% |=========================| 2.5 MB    06:10
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 8df56d05
public key not available for //var/cache/yum/flash/packages/flash-plugin-9.0.48.0-a.i386.rpm
```

Any little help is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looking like a harmless warning. rpm did not find the gpg signing key, or something like that. Is this the end of the output? If so, you may need to configure yum to ignore the signing key issue.

Comment: How can I be sure that the package was actually installed though?

Comment: How can I be sure that the package was actually installed though?

Comment: @selvin: `yum list flash-plugin` or `yum info flash-plugin` should work. See  [Basic Yum Commands and how to use them](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumCommands).